# How to retrieve all the data from kubectl describe pods <namespace> from an in-cluster client-go api call

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, client-go

I need to grab some pod information which will be used for some unit tests which will be run in-cluster. I need all the information which kubectl describe po  gives but from an in cluster api call.

I have some working code which makes an api call to apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods, and have installed the metrics-server on minikube for testing which is all working and gives me output like this:

```
Namespace: kube-system
Pod name: heapster-rgnlj
SelfLink: /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/heapster-rgnlj
CreationTimestamp: 2019-09-10 12:27:13 +0000 UTC
Window: 30s
Timestamp: 2019-09-10 12:26:23 +0000 UTC
Name: heapster
Cpu usage: 82166n
Mem usage: 19420Ki
```

```
...
func getMetrics(clientset *kubernetes.Clientset, pods *PodMetricsList) error {
    data, err := clientset.RESTClient().Get().AbsPath("apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods").DoRaw()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &pods)
    return err
}

func main() {

    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var pods PodMetricsList
    err = getMetrics(clientset, &pods)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, m := range pods.Items {

        fmt.Print("Namespace: ", m.Metadata.Namespace, "\n", "Pod name: ", m.Metadata.Name, "\n", )
        fmt.Print("SelfLink: ", m.Metadata.SelfLink, "\n", "CreationTimestamp: ", m.Metadata.CreationTimestamp, "\n", )
        fmt.Print("Window: ", m.Window, "\n", "Timestamp: ", m.Timestamp, "\n", )

        for _, c := range m.Containers {
            fmt.Println("Name:", c.Name)
            fmt.Println("Cpu usage:", c.Usage.CPU)
            fmt.Println("Mem usage:", c.Usage.Memory, "\n")
...
```

As I say, what i really need is what you'd get with a 'describe pods' type call. Having looked through the kubernetes source this NodeDescriber looks like the right type of function, but I'm slightly at a loss as to how to integrate / implement it to get the desired results.

kubernetes/pkg/printers/internalversion/describe.go

Line 2451 in 4f2d7b9

func (d *NodeDescriber) Describe(namespace, name string, describerSettings...etc)

I'm new to Go and not particularly familiar with kubernetes.
Any pointers as to how to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [describePod](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/versioned/describe.go#L668) and [Describe](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L693) funcs from staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/versioned/describe.go should give you a better picture of how to do this. And since [Describe](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L693) and [PodDescriber](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/versioned/describe.go#L628) are public, you can reuse these for your use case.

You could couple this with a [CoreV1Client](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#CoreV1Client) which has a [Pods](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#CoreV1Client.Pods) func, that returns a [PodInterface](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#PodInterface) that has a [List](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#PodList) func which would return a list of [Pod](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#Pod) objects for the given namespace.

Those pod objects will provide the Name needed for the [Describe](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L693) func, the Namespace is already known, and the [describe.DescriberSettings](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/interface.go#L49) is just a struct type that you could inline to enable showing events in the [Describe](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L693) output.

Using the [List](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#PodList) func will only list the pods that one time. If you're interested in having this list be updated regularly, you might want to look at the Reflector and Informer patterns; both of which are largely implemented in the [tools/cache](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache) package, and the docs briefly explain this concept in the [Efficient detection of changes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll delve into this and give it a shot. I'll report back when I have something working. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try, but I would suggest to start with:

**1.** using kubectl with  --verbosity option to see the full api request

```
 kubectl describe pod xxx -v=8
```

like:

```
  GET https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events?fieldSelector=involvedObject.uid%3Ddd77c4aa-28e6-4bf0-8dfe-0d8610cbe9c9%2CinvolvedObject.name%3Dmy-app%2CinvolvedObject.namespace%3Ddefault
```

It contains fields related to your POD: **fieldSelector=involvedObject.uid, involvedObject.name, involvedObject.namespace**

**2.** I thing the good start it will be the code from github [func describePod](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b6a0718858876bbf8cedaeeb47e6de7e650a6c5b/pkg/kubectl/describe/versioned/describe.go#L619) to start with.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up just writing out a struct to map the results from a /api/v1/pods query and just iterating through ranges to get what I need.

Here's the struct in case it saves anybody else some time.

```
type ApiV1PodMetricsList struct {
    Kind       string `json:"kind"`
    APIVersion string `json:"apiVersion"`
    Metadata   struct {
        SelfLink        string `json:"selfLink"`
        ResourceVersion string `json:"resourceVersion"`
    } `json:"metadata"`
    Items []struct {
        Metadata struct {
            Name              string    `json:"name"`
            Namespace         string    `json:"namespace"`
            SelfLink          string    `json:"selfLink"`
            UID               string    `json:"uid"`
            ResourceVersion   string    `json:"resourceVersion"`
            CreationTimestamp time.Time `json:"creationTimestamp"`
            Labels            struct {
                Run string `json:"run"`
            } `json:"labels"`
        } `json:"metadata"`
        Spec struct {
            Volumes []struct {
                Name   string `json:"name"`
                Secret struct {
                    SecretName  string `json:"secretName"`
                    DefaultMode string `json:"defaultMode"`
                } `json:"secret"`
            } `json:"volumes"`
            Containers []struct {
                Name      string `json:"name"`
                Image     string `json:"image"`
                Resources struct {
                } `json:"resources"`
                VolumeMounts []struct {
                    Name      string `json:"name"`
                    ReadOnly  string `json:"readOnly"`
                    MountPath string `json:"mountPath"`
                } `json:"volumeMounts"`
                TerminationMessagePath   string `json:"terminationMessagePath"`
                TerminationMessagePolicy string `json:"terminationMessagePolicy"`
                ImagePullPolicy          string `json:"imagePullPolicy"`
                Stdin                    string `json:"stdin"`
                StdinOnce                string `json:"stdinOnce"`
                Tty                      string `json:"tty"`
            } `json:"containers"`
            RestartPolicy                 string `json:"restartPolicy"`
            TerminationGracePeriodSeconds string `json:"terminationGracePeriodSeconds"`
            DnsPolicy                     string `json:"dnsPolicy"`
            ServiceAccountName            string `json:"serviceAccountName"`
            ServiceAccount                string `json:"serviceAccount"`
            NodeName                      string `json:"nodeName"`
            SecurityContext               struct {
            } `json:"securityContext"`
            SchedulerName string `json:"schedulerName"`
            Tolerations   []struct {
                Key               string `json:"key"`
                Operator          string `json:"operator"`
                Effect            string `json:"effect"`
                TolerationSeconds string `json:"tolerationSeconds"`
            } `json:"tolerations"`
            Priority           string `json:"priority"`
            EnableServiceLinks string `json:"enableServiceLinks"`
        } `json:"spec"`
        Status struct {
            Phase      string `json:"phase"`
            Conditions []struct {
                Type               string    `json:"type"`
                Status             string    `json:"status"`
                LastProbeTime      time.Time `json:"lastProbeTime"`
                LastTransitionTime time.Time `json:"lastTransitionTime"`
                Reason             string    `json:"reason"`
            } `json:"conditions"`
            HostIP            string `json:"hostIP"`
            PodIP             string `json:"podIP"`
            StartTime         string `json:"startTime"`
            ContainerStatuses []struct {
                Name  string `json:"name"`
                State struct {
                    Terminated struct {
                        ExitCode    string    `json:"exitCode"`
                        Reason      string    `json:"reason"`
                        StartedAt   time.Time `json:"startedAt"`
                        FinishedAt  time.Time `json:"finishedAt"`
                        ContainerID string    `json:"containerID"`
                    } `json:"terminated"`
                } `json:"state"`
                LastState struct {
                } `json:"lastState"`
                Ready        bool   `json:"ready"`
                RestartCount int64  `json:"restartCount"`
                Image        string `json:"image"`
                ImageID      string `json:"imageID"`
                ContainerID  string `json:"containerID"`
            } `json:"containerStatuses"`
            QosClass string `json:"qosClass"`
        } `json:"status"`
    } `json:"items"`
}
```